# Elasticsearch integration with Hibernate Search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I am trying to integrate Elasticsearch with Hibernate Search.

For this i have upgraded some versions:

- JDK version 1.7 to 1.8
- Hibernate ORM version 4.1.9 to 5.2.12
- Hibernate Search version 4.0.0 to 5.8.1

While runnint tests I am getting an error:

Code:

```
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.search.bridge.spi.IndexManagerTypeSpecificBridgeProvider: Provider org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.bridge.impl.ElasticsearchBridgeProvider not a subtype
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:459)
at org.hibernate.search.cfg.impl.DelegatingClassLoaderService.loadJavaServices(DelegatingClassLoaderService.java:74)
at org.hibernate.search.bridge.impl.BridgeFactory.<init>(BridgeFactory.java:65)
at org.hibernate.search.engine.metadata.impl.AnnotationMetadataProvider.<init>(AnnotationMetadataProvider.java:126)
at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.initDocumentBuilders(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:379)
at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.createNewFactoryState(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:243)
at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildNewSearchFactory(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:199)
at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildSearchIntegrator(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:127)
at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.boot(HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.java:113)
at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.sessionFactoryCreated(HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.java:79)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:375)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:511)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:495)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
... 60 more
```

Can anyone assist me to solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you are just trying it out, why don't you use the setup described in [the manual](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=5.8#_getting_started_and_configuration)?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect this sort of errors if you have a dependency that is not inline with the others.

Do you use the same version for the hibernate-search orm and engine dependencies and the Elasticsearch specific module?

Comment: I'm quite sure Guillaume is spot on. Also make sure you don't have additional copies of (older) Hibernate Search jars on the classpath.

Comment: Hi Guillaume & Sanne,
Thanks for fast reply..

Iam using same versions of hibernate-search orm, engine and Elsaticsearch dependencies. 
These are the hibernate jars iam using in my application 

1.hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final
2.hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final
3.hibernate-ehcache-5.2.12.Final
4.hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final
5.hibernate-search-5.8.1.Final
6.hibernate-search-analyzers-4.5.3.Final
7.hibernate-search-elasticsearch-5.8.1.Final
8.hibernate-search-engine-5.8.1.Final
9.hibernate-search-orm-5.8.1.Final
10.hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final

Comment: This one looks suspicious: hibernate-search-analyzers-4.5.3.Final

Comment: I have removed that jar from my tomcat lib folder. But again iam getting same error.