# is Hibernate Elasticsearch compatible with wildfly 14

Tags: java, hibernate, elasticsearch, wildfly, hibernate-search

I am trying to index my entities on AWS Elasticsearch cluster, I am currently using hibernate search and local file for it. Therefore, the hibernate integration with elasticsearch is the only option I have, I've followed the hibernate search [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#elasticsearch-integration) but it ends up with

```
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.search.bridge.spi.IndexManagerTypeSpecificBridgeProvider: Provider org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.bridge.impl.ElasticsearchBridgeProvider not a subtype
```

- I tried to remove all the jars and clean install maven once again, it didn't change anything
- I've tried to add the hibernate-search-elasticsearch as a module in wildfly but ends up with many issues as well like Lucene query parser is not found in the class loader (maybe I missed up something while adding the jar as a module )
- As I understood I don't need server provisioning since I am using the version which is supported by wildfly (correct me if I am wrong).

**I am using:**

- Wildfly server 14.0.1
- Hibernate core 5.3.6.Final
- Hibernate search orm 5.10.3.Final
- Hibernate search elasticsearch 5.10.3.Final

any ideas what could be wrong? and the better question am I adding the correct dependencies for wildfly?

P.S I know the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437662/elasticsearch-integration-with-hibernate-search) was asked before but the answer didn't help at all.

Comment: Last time I checked, the Hibernate Search Elasticsearch integration was not included in WildFly. We will need more information regarding how you added it to WildFly exactly. You *should* be using server provisioning as described in https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-configuration-deploy-on-wildfly

Comment: I kinda dumbly added the jars and module to hibernate/search/elasticsearch/5.10.3.Final..

Comment: @yrodiere I will give it a try with the server provisioning, any plan to add the integration as an embedded dependency with the search orm?

Comment: Not with Search 5, because the Elasticsearch integration is still experimental. We will probably add the Elasticsearch backend when Wildfly moves to Search 6 (still in development).

Comment: @yrodiere hope to see it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that needed to be done is to add the dependency for hibernate elasticsearch as compile scope and add those properties in persistence.xml.

```
      <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate" />
      <property name="wildfly.jpa.hibernate.search.module" value="org.hibernate.search.orm" />
```